# Determine if there are n instances of any value in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<int>` with values like { 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1 }, only much longer. I would like to test if there are *n* instances of the same value - any value - in the list. For example, if I had a function like `bool duplicateCount(int n, IEnumerable<int> collection)`, using the above list:

> duplicateCount(4, list); // false
>
> duplicateCount(3, list); // true, as there are 3x '1's

In the past I would resolve a problem like this by building a `Dictionary<int, int>` and count the instances of each member. However, in order to help me learn Linq, I would like to try to implement a solution with that technology.

I have written a query that uses groupby, below, but I'm having trouble getting the number of elements in each group. Any advice on how to proceed here?

```
var q = from i in list group i by i into g select g.Count();
```

Comment: What does your `GroupBy` code look like?  The number of elements in each grouping can be obtained by `grouping.Count()`.

Comment: Your query will give you a colleciton of the counts.  You just need to see if any equal n like `q.Any(count => count == n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a `GroupBy` and then checking if `Any` group has a `Count` greater than or equal to the number

```
public bool duplicateCount(int n, IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
    return collection.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() >= n)
}
```

Or the following if you want to determine if there is any value repeated exactly n times.

```
public bool duplicateCount(int n, IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
    return collection.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() == n)
}
```

There is also query syntax, though I think in this case method syntax looks better, especially since you cannot translate `Any` to query syntax.

```
public bool duplicateCount(int n, IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
    return (from item in collection
            group by item into grp
            select grp.Count()).Any(count => count == n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense now! Generalizing this one level, looking at groups of groups, what if I wanted to determine if there are m instances of n duplicates? E.g. on `{9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 7, 7}`, I should get `true` for n=3, m=1; and also true for n=2, m=2; but `false` for n=3, m=2.

Comment: Just filter the groups that have a count of n and see if you have m of them. `collection.GroupBy(x=>x).Where(g=>g.Count() == n).Count() == m`

Answer (score 0):

something other than lambda expressions

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,2,2,2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

        var q = (from i in list
                 where i == 2
                 select i).Count();
```

Comment: If you filter it to one value there's no point in doing a group by.